# Shortest route algo terribly slow

Tags: c#, time-limit-exceeded, pathfinding, unity3d

First post. I posted this on stack as well but somebody suggested I post it here too/instead.

I wrote a shortest-path script for a Unity game project, and while it works, it gets so slow when applied at scale that it crashes Unity when executed. This is to say, it works slowly for a single test character, but scale is required for the project.

I didn't really follow any of the known shortest path techniques to create it, rather I did it myself. The way it works is that it spawns a series of recursive methods each containing a for loop to explore each possible node in the network, bringing with each method a pathway and a list of pathways. If the target is found, or if the current path gets longer than a known path, or if a new node has already been inspected, the method terminates.

Here is some code. I have excluded the method that initially calls this recursive method:

```
void ExploreBranch(List<Point> stem, List<List<Point>> masterList, Point target)
{
    if (masterList.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < masterList.Count; m++)
        {
            List<Point> thisList = masterList[m];
            if (stem.Count + 1 >= thisList.Count) 
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    Point lastPoint = stem[stem.Count - 1];
    for (int c = 0; c < lastPoint.Connections.Count; c++)
    {
        List<Point> updatedRoute = new List<Point>(stem);
        Point newConnection = new Point();
        newConnection = lastPoint.Connections[c];
        if (newConnection == target)
        {
            updatedRoute.Add(newConnection);
            masterList.Add(updatedRoute);
            return;
        }
        if (updatedRoute.Contains(newConnection))
        {    
            continue;
        }
        updatedRoute.Add(newConnection);
        ExploreBranch(updatedRoute, inspected, masterList, target);
    }
}
```

So, basically this is nowhere near efficient enough and I can't figure out a way within this basic framework to improve it. I am now leaning in the direction of starting over or trying to get really experimental, but thought I would check here first.

One of the main things here is that I need to preserve the actual pathway, which the character needs to use and follow within the game. So it's not just that I need to know how short the path can be, I also need the actual path.

Any ideas would be most appreciated.

Comment: Pathfinding is a _notoriously_ difficult problem, especially when balancing performance and scalability. It may be considerably more fruitful to look at existing pathfinding algorithms because this is not something anyone can draw up easily from scratch.

Comment: I actually ended up switching to a breadth first algo, which is working much better. It turns out the one I had made was basically a depth first search, ideally bad for what I was trying to do.

Comment: Not enough code for review. Btw, this code can be optimized. But I can't figure out what is `Point` and how the method is used, show it. _I have excluded the method that initially calls this recursive method_ - please show it, it can give a sense what's really happening. Then It isn't clear how the result returned, the methond returns `void`. Can you explain how the result is used? Show the code.

Comment: `ExploreBranch(updatedRoute, inspected, masterList, target);` isn't a recursive call but call of the other mehtod overload. Where's it?

Answer (score 1):

`void ExploreBranch(List<Point> stem, List<List<Point>> masterList, Point target)`

Based on this signature, I can't understand what this function takes in (what is a "masterList"? what is a "stem"?). Since it returns `void`, I can't understand what it returns or updates, if anything. Include ALL your code in a short working example, and clearly document what each function takes in and returns. I recommend reading some standard library function documentation--look for descriptions that are 1-2 sentences or less. You can still understand what the function will do--try to follow this style.

"My path finding is too slow and I don't know why" is a good trigger that you should try asymptotic analysis of algorithm runtime, if you know how. If you expect to solve problems like this regularly, you should learn how if not (it's not acutally hard, it's just that it's a common college intro class and people make it way too formal). And/or, read existing path-finding algorithms.